# GSL linear algebra example fails

Tags: c, linear-algebra, algebra, gsl

I recently installed GSL for use in my computing homework. I installed it from a pre built library and linked it to CodeBlocks, then ran the test example for GSL (the bessel function) to make sure it worked. Everything going fine.

Then I tried the example for linear algebra given here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linear-Algebra-Examples.html#Linear-Algebra-Examples

I get an odd error message:

```
gls: ..\linalg\lu.c:63: ERROR: LU decomposition requires square matrix
Default GSL error handler invoked.

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Then the program crashes with a 225 error code.

Putting in markers, I know my program makes it to the decomposition command before failing (which would be a good guess from the error code).

This has been confirmed by 2 of 3 people. One runs a Windows machine with code blocks like me, and uses the same pre built package I do. The other runs on a mac with a different piece of software to write, compile, and run his C. The third person is on Windows again, used the same prebuilt installation, but his runs fine in codeblocks, so I don't know what the thing is there.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file and line in your error message we can see:

```
int
gsl_linalg_LU_decomp (gsl_matrix * A, gsl_permutation * p, int *signum)
{
    if (A->size1 != A->size2)
    {
        GSL_ERROR ("LU decomposition requires square matrix", GSL_ENOTSQR);
    }
```

The code is checking to insure that the inputted matrix is a square matrix (*i.e.* same number of rows and columns).  Furthermore, if we peek inside `gsl_errno.h` we can find the defination of `GSL_ERROR` as:

```
#define GSL_ERROR(reason, gsl_errno) \
       do { \
       gsl_error (reason, __FILE__, __LINE__, gsl_errno) ; \
       return gsl_errno ; \
    } while (0)
```

So in effect, an error message is shown, and then `GSL_ERROR` causes your program to exit and returns an error code to the shell.

At this point, if I had to guess, you failed to copy the example program that you linked into your development environment correctly, as `a_data` does define a square matrix.

Hope this helps 
T.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didnt help. I didnt retype the example, but instead dragged the whole thing as one, so I dont see that as a source of errors. Ill have another look though.